# How to select an entity using selectedEntity?

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I am trying to select an entity using selectedEntity. I do it like this

```
btn.onclick = function() {
                for (var i in viewer.dataSources._dataSources) { 
                    if (viewer.dataSources._dataSources[i].name == btns_class[j].value){
                        viewer.selectedEntity = viewer.dataSources._dataSources[i]
                        viewer.zoomTo(viewer.dataSources._dataSources[i])
                    } 
                }
            }
```

But I get not what I want, the object remains unselected. How can I make an object selected?

Here is what I have:

[image: here is what i have]

This is what I want to get:

[image: this is what i want to get]

Comment: Is the if code triggered at all?  What is `btns_class[j]`?

Comment: @James if the code works I'm sure. btns_class[j] — button by which the object should be selected. button works

Comment: I was wondering if the code inside your `if` block is ever executed.  You could put a console.log in there to check.  And if not, I suspect that btns_class[j] isn't what you expect.

Comment: @James, i have console.log() in if block. I do console.log(viewer.dataSources._dataSources[i]) and get the desired object in the console. btns_class[j] is just a button for the viewer.dataSources._dataSources[i] object

Answer (score 0):

In Cesium, dataSources are collections of entities.  You cannot set `selectedEntity` to be an entire dataSource, instead you must pick just one entity from within the dataSource.  So, this line is the main problem:

```js
viewer.selectedEntity = viewer.dataSources._dataSources[i]
```

Also, the `_` underscore prefix indicates Cesium's "private" variables.  Ideally one should avoid using those in production code, as they may change without warning between versions of Cesium.

So for example, this will find the named dataSource and select the first entity in the collection:

```js
var dataSource = viewer.dataSources.getByName(btns_class[j].value)[0];
if (Cesium.defined(dataSource)) {
    viewer.selectedEntity = dataSource.entities.values[0];
}
```

Also, if you want the camera to focus on the entity, you may wish to set `viewer.trackedEntity` to the same entity.  This is similar to a double-click action in Cesium, where `selectedEntity` and `trackedEntity` are both set to the target object.